Variogram matrix and covariance matrix
Let $\textbf{W}$ be a mean-zero Gaussian random vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the covariance matrix $A$. Let $\vec{1} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ be a vector of $1$s.
We define its variogram matrix by $\Gamma_{ij} = E(W_i-W_j) = A_{ii}+A_{jj}-2A_{ij}$.
Let $\textbf{W}'$ be the random vector defined by $\textbf{W}' = \textbf{W} - \bar{W}\vec{1}$. That is, $\textbf{W}_j' = W_j - \frac{1}{d} \sum_{i=1}^d W_i$.
How do we show that the covariance matrix of $\textbf{W}'$ equals
$$\frac{-1}{2}(I - \frac{\vec{1} \vec{1}^T}{d})\Gamma(I - \frac{\vec{1} \vec{1}^T}{d})$$?
For example, we can write the variance of $W_1 - \bar{W}$ as $A_{11} - \frac{2}{d}\sum_{i=1}^d A_{1i} + \frac{1}{d^2} \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}$, but for the other expression, I can't seem to make it equal to each other. I assume there must be an easy way to see this, but I'm not seeing it.
Thank you.
This is from the paper "Graphical lasso for extremes".


I believe $\vec{1}^T \vec{1}$ in the paper is supposed to be $\vec{1} \vec{1}^T$.
